# Prove that, $\exists k \leqslant 0(\in \mathbb{Z})$ such that $p(i)=q(k)$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Let $P(x)=x^{7}+x^{6}+b_{5} x^{5}+b_{4} x^{4}+\ldots+b_{1} x+b_{0}$ and $q(x)=C_{5} x^{5}+C_{4} x^{4}+\ldots+C_{1} x+C_{0}$. Given that $p(i)=q(i) \space \forall i=1,2,3, \ldots, 6$. Prove that, $\exists \space k \leqslant 0(\in \mathbb{Z})$ such that $p(i)=q(k)$.

---

I am not able to do much on this question. The only thing I did was to assume a polynomial $g(x)$ such that $g(x)=P(x)- q(x)$ and then try to check if I get anything for $g(1),g(2),g(3), \dots , g(6)$. But I didn't get any satisfactory result.

Comment: Do you mean $p(k) = q(k)$ above?

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer I'm not sure. This is what was given in the problem

Comment: Ah, I guess it was a printing mistake then, especially in view of the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume it's intended that the coefficients $b_i,c_i$ are complex numbers, and that the problem is to show that $p(k)=q(k)$ for some integer $k\le 0$.

As you suggested, let $g(x)=p(x)-q(x)$. Then
$$
g(x)=x^7+x^6+\sum_{i=0}^5 (b_i-c_i)x^i
$$
By hypothesis we have $g(i)=0$ for $i=1,...,6$, hence by The Complete Factorization Theorem, we get
$$
g(x)=(x-u)(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)(x-5)(x-6)
$$
for some $u\in\mathbb{C}$.

By Vieta's formula, the roots of $g$ sum to $-1$, which gives
$$
u+1+2+3+4+5+6=-1
$$
so $u=-22$.

Hence $p(-22)=q(-22)$.